# Is there a @@trancount equivalent in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking for some way to replicate the behavior of @@trancount from T-SQL in Oracle, I can't figure out a clever way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: Why do you need to replicate this in Oracle? What's the context for you wanting to replicate its behaviour?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the problem you are trying to solve, rather than just referring to something that exists in another platform.

Comment: @@trancount is just a counter of how many begin/end blocks are in TSQL connection. the counter goes to 0 when there is a rollback. I think you don't need anything special for doing that, it can be easily done with a variable.

Comment: Actually, I just need a way to know if there is a transaction open in the current session. If there is no pending transaction, I would continue with the whole procedure, otherwise, I would create a savepoint and discard the subsequent code.

Comment: It really sounds like you're trying to turn Oracle into SQL Server, when in fact they work differently. Please ask a new question with an example of what you're trying to do, and we can help find a better way of doing it in Oracle. Because checking if you're in a transaction before doing something isn't something you'd typically need to do in Oracle!

Comment: I would echo and expand a bit on @Boneist.  Oracle is not just mssql with different syntax/function names.  They differ greatly in their fundamental architecture, and this is particularly true in the way they handle the concept of transactions, and in the way they handle locking.  It would be best if you forget any preconceived technical approaches and describe the _business problem_ you expect to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit foreign in Oracle, since you generally only have a single transaction open in a session. [See documentation for more on the concept of transactions in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/transactions.html)

But you can query `v$transaction` to see open transactions in your current session.

```
select count(*) from v$transaction t
join v$session s on t.ses_addr = s.saddr
  and s.AUDSID = Sys_Context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to simulate `@@trancount`, you can follow this approach

> Returns the number of BEGIN TRANSACTION statements that have occurred
> on the current connection.
> On TSQL

```
PRINT @@TRANCOUNT  
--  The BEGIN TRAN statement will increment the  
--  transaction count by 1.  
BEGIN TRAN  
    PRINT @@TRANCOUNT  
    BEGIN TRAN  
        PRINT @@TRANCOUNT  
--  The COMMIT statement will decrement the transaction count by 1.  
    COMMIT  
    PRINT @@TRANCOUNT  
COMMIT  
PRINT @@TRANCOUNT  
--Results  
--0  
--1  
--2  
--1  
--0
```

In Oracle there is no such functionality, but can be emulated by a variable.

```
set serveroutput on 
declare
vtrancount pls_integer := 0;
--  The BEGIN statement will increment the transaction count by 1.  
begin
 vtrancount := vtrancount + 1;
 dbms_output.put_line(vtrancount);
 -- ... dml 
    begin   
        vtrancount := vtrancount + 1;
        dbms_output.put_line(vtrancount);
        ... dml 
        commit;  
        vtrancount := vtrancount - 1;
        dbms_output.put_line(vtrancount);
    end;
commit; 
vtrancount := vtrancount - 1;
dbms_output.put_line(vtrancount);
exception when others then 
    vtrancount := 0;
    rollback;
    raise;
end;
/
```